# Magento doesn't show CVV for customers when checking out

Tags: magento, paypal, invisible

I'm using Magento 1.9.2 with latest updates installed. If a customer checks out and gets to the payment section, he/she enters credit card information and will be able to see everything on the screen EXCEPT the CVV. If you try to add anything in that box, nothing shows up and it seems like that field is not allowing numbers to show up.

I've tested an actual transaction on (Live) and I was able to complete the transaction. The issue is if you don't click and add any numbers in the CVV, you will get the error message that you're missing the CVV. but you can click on it and type the "invisible numbers" and it will complete the transaction.

How can this be fixed? I would like to allow numbers to show for the customer or remove the CVV completely.

PS: I'm using Paypal pro

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: Could you provide us with a link to the shop?

Comment: @Gerard: I've disabled the credit card feature in my website since this is on production. 
I will move the question to the link provided. <br> Thanks!